# How to open a specific directory or folder when click on the "Finder" folder icon on OSX Ventura

Tags: macos, mac, folders, open-directory

When I click on the "Finder" icon on my bottom bar, it always open the "Recent" folder like this:

[image]

Now, I want to open a specific folder for example "Documents" when click on the "Finder" icon. How am I able to do that?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. click on your "Finder" icon
   [image]
2. Click on the top left "Finder" option and then select "Settings" from the dropdown
   [image]
3. Now on the Finder settings window, select "General" and then click on the "Drop down" menu option
   [image]
4. Now select the directory or folder you want to assign on it.
   [image]